# Cannot import any modules (installed used pip) in python 2.7.14

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I downloaded the source code of python 2.7.14 and built it and installed it on linux ( Red Hat 4.8.5-16 ). I have earlier installed `python-magic` and `requests` libraries. Now when I try to import modules installed using `pip`, I get this:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.14 (default, Nov  9 2017, 09:05:45) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import magic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named magic
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

while similar thing works perfectly fine in python 2.7.5 (default with the RHEL system)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import magic
>>> import requests
>>>
```

Am I missing any configuration step here?

Comment: Whoever downvotes, please add a reason for the same. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules installed via `pip` are only available to the standard python version. You need to install your desired packages for the non-standard python versions as well (see also [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/installing/index.html))

```
python2 -m pip install python-magic
python2 -m pip install requests
```

Comment: After running `$ python2.7 -m pip install python-magic` I get `/usr/local/bin/python2.7: No module named pip`

Comment: Just as any other module, `pip` is specific to the python version. The link in my answer has information about how to install `pip`. I think it's `python2 -m ensurepip`

Answer (score 0):

your `pip` is default set for version

> $ python
>
> Python 2.7.5

SO if you want to install module for

> $ python2
>
> Python 2.7.14

use `python2 -m pip install module_name`

Answer (score -1):

The `sys.path` must be different for the two installations. That's a list of folders that Python checks for imports.

It's probably simplest to just symlink the one for wherever pip installs to into the modules folder for 2.7.14.